# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when importing numpy

Tags: python, module, virtualenv, pickle

I'm working with a project and somewhere down the line my I have to uninstall and reinstall numpy to fix a problem, but then this happened

> Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   File "ori2.py", line 3, in <module>
     import numpy as np
    File "/home/tsoi/Documents/environments/testvenv/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
      from . import add_newdocs
   File "/home/tsoi/Documents/environments/testvenv/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
     from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
    File "/home/tsoi/Documents/environments/testvenv/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
     from .type_check import *
   File "/home/tsoi/Documents/environments/testvenv/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
     import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
   File "/home/tsoi/Documents/environments/testvenv/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
     from . import numeric
   File "/home/tsoi/Documents/environments/testvenv/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 43, in <module>
     import pickle
   File "/home/tsoi/Documents/environments/testvenv/Traffic-rec/pickle.py", line 1
     from ~/Documents/environments/testvenv/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy import numpy as np
          ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have also tried

```
import sys
sys.path.append('~/Documents/environments/testvenv/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy')
```

when importing numpy but the same error occured, This hasn't happened before and it's been annoying for me. This is the part of my code that I think is relevant to this problem:

> ```
> from __future__ import print_function
> #from comet_ml import Experiment
> import numpy as np
> import tensorflow as tf
> import keras
> from keras.datasets import mnist
> from keras.models import Sequential
> from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
> from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
> from keras import backend as K
> from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
> from keras.models import Model
> from keras.layers import Input, Dense
> from keras.models import load_model
> import cv2
> import os
> import glob
> from os import path
> import random
> ```

Comment: You named a file `pickle.py` and put some weird junk in it. Delete that file; it's hiding the `pickle` module.

Comment: go the the terminal & run pythin an dthe manually do import and see what it say `>>> import numpy as np`  this way at least you will get to know if its problem with `numpy` or its your code messing soewhere.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah it worked, I didn't know naming a .py after a module/package could be the problem, Thank you I thought it was because I installed two different version of numpy causes it.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: 
Yeah you right [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112)

numpy is importing your file '/home/tsoi/Documents/environments/testvenv/Traffic-rec/pickle.py' instead of the pickle module, delete the file or rename it, then the problem should be fixed.

Comment: Yes I imported numpy for python3.6, but the problem was because I named a .py after a module, changing the .py name solved it but thanks for checking out my situation.

Comment: Sorry, but i edited my answer 8 hours ago. What are you commenting to?